# Save 2D array as xls file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have 2d array and I need save this array data as xls file

I am trying make this using `PHPExcel`

```
include 'PHPExcel.php';


  $data = array(
    array("firstname" => "Mary", "lastname" => "Johnson", "age" => 25),
    array("firstname" => "Amanda", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 18),
  );

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($data);

$objPHPExcel->save("test.xls");
```

But this gives error:  `Call to undefined method PHPExcel::save()`

What is right way for saving array as xls using `PHPExcel` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

similar to Sailinthorns answer

```
  include 'PHPExcel.php';

  $data = array(
    array("firstname" => "Mary", "lastname" => "Johnson", "age" => 25),
    array("firstname" => "Amanda", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 18),
  );

  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($data);

  // Redirect output to a clientâ€™s web browser (Excel5)
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.xls"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
  // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

  // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
  header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
  header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
  header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
  header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
  $objWriter->save("test.xls");
```

Comment: it creates the xls file in the same directory as the php file running it, check the web for the 'test.xls'

Comment: try using at the end header('Location: test.xls'); not the cleanest way to do it, but just to get you thinking

Comment: just updated my answer based on the documentation on how to properly set the headers for download, note this downloads the file and saves a copy on the website

Answer (score 4):

It seems as if there is no such function.

if u check the Hallo World example at [http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home) u may see that they are not using `$objPHPExcel->save("test.xls");`

but

```
include 'PHPExcel.php';
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```